# twilio rest API for event registration and listening

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I'm using twilio rest API to implement a chat iOS app in objective-c. Though twilio has iOS SDK, I'm required to use rest API only. My question is does anyone know how to use twilio rest API for event registration and listening, such as message sending?

Comment: I've answered the question, but I'd also love to know why you are only able to use the REST API to build chat? Could you please email me at philnash@twilio.com? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [Twilio Programmable Chat API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat) uses [webhooks to notify your application of incoming messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/webhooks). Note though that webhooks are not fired for events that are initiated from the REST API. Since you are in control of sending messages via the REST API you should be able to notify other parts of your application when you do so too.